# ARKit and ResNet 50

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

I made recognition using ResNet 50. How do I add the ability to find out the distance from one object to another using ARKit, so that the name of the object is displayed on the screen in three-dimensional letters?

I did it in UIKit's Storyboard, not using SwiftUI. I want to do as in the picture.

[image]